# Two column UICollectionView with header

Tags: uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout, uicollectionreusableview

I have a layout that has two columns side by side. Is there a simple way to do this using a single UICollectionView? The only requirements are that the solution must work for iOS 8 and the cells must stack vertically in each column like this:

```
   -----------------
   |       A       |
   |       B       |
   -----------------
   |   C   |   E   |
   |   C   |   F   |
   |   D   |       |
   |   E   |       |
   -----------------
```

The stacked Cs demonstrate that the cells in the left and right columns can be different heights, so it's not enough to just paint them left, right, left, right.

Comment: Couldn't you just make a CollectionView with 2 columns and then make the first cell take up all the space using the Delegate method:
`collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` and make the second cell (next to the first one) with a width of 0?

Comment: I could do that, but wouldn't it potentially make big vertical gaps between cells in the same column if, say for example, C and E where different heights? (I just updated the layout above to reflect that).

Comment: I use this library for my layout, if I understand your question correctly: https://github.com/chiahsien/CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout

Comment: Did you end up solving it?

Answer (score 2):

This is actually pretty straightforward using a `UICollectionView` with flow layout. Since each cell can have a dynamic height, the only thing you need to require is that each cell has a width of 160 (or half the collection view width). Then implement `collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` so that each item can return it's appropriate height.

Since each cell has a dynamic height though, you could end up with one column a lot longer than another. If you also want equal column heights, then you'll want to shuffle the order of your list in such a way so that the height for the first half of items is approx the height of the other half.

[image]